# how to create json response in spring boot java like this as shown when the following attributes are not present in json request

Tags: java, json, spring-boot, exception

I am creating an controller where there is certain attributes in json which is an doing in postman a POST request like this if all attributes are posted then its fine
[image: this is the image if all attributes are there in json]

if one then is missing then it would look like this
[image]

i want this response when some attribute is missing how to implement this
[image]

Comment: Add code always as text not as image.

Comment: Also show the relevant code. Not only the json.

Answer (score 1):

This is normally implemented in two steps:

1. Implement a validation mechanism for the method that handles the incoming request. Normally you would throw an exception here if the input is incorrect, in your example a missing JSON key.
2. Implement a global error handler that will process the exception from point 1 and format the response as JSON.

For point 1 the usual choice is the Java Bean Validation framework because it's integrated with Spring Boot and allows to define validation constraints with annotations like `@NotEmpty`. You can take a look at [this example](https://reflectoring.io/bean-validation-with-spring-boot/).

For point 2 the usual choice is [`@RestControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/RestControllerAdvice.html) or [`@ControllerAdvice`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/bind/annotation/ControllerAdvice.html). You would have to understand your service web server setup to implement it properly e.g. it might behave differently if you use Spring WebFlux.